# How to check if SOAPUI Datasource columns exists using groovy

Tags: groovy, datasource, soapui

I am trying to write a groovy script where I want to check if a column in DataSource of SOAPUI exists or not. I am not able to find any solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :) Try this

```
// dataSourceName = name of the datasource
dataSourceStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps.dataSourceName
// get all properties as a hash map
def hashMap = dataSourceStep.getProperties()

Boolean isItFound = false
// give the column name as a string
def intendedColumnName = "ThisColumn"
// calling the function
isItFound = printMap (hashMap, log, intendedColumnName, isItFound)

// Function to iterate through all columns and compare with the intended column name
public Boolean printMap(Map map, log, String thisIntendedColumnName, Boolean thisIsItFound) 
{
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry element = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    //log.info pair.getKey();
    if (element.getKey()==thisIntendedColumnName)
    {
    thisIsItFound = true
    break
    }
    }
    return thisIsItFound
}
// To display the result
log.info isItFound
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped me :)